# EthersJS not properly returning a value from a smart contract on function call

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, remix, ethers.js

I'm working on a DApp on the Ethereum network, and am using EthersJS on a react frontend to interact with a smart contract. I've deployed my smart contract and all seems to be going fine with ***most*** of my function calls, however for some reason I'm unable to call a couple of the contract functions from EtherJS properly. Here's what I mean...

In Remix (where I deployed the smart contract) I am able to call the view no problem; I'm getting the result I expect. [image: Remix showing the correct value]

However, when I call the same view from EthersJS, I'm getting the following:
[image: EthersJS returning nothing for this view and this view alone.]

As you can see in the screenshot, the view call from EthersJS returns `0x00` instead of the desired value.

Here's the snippet of the smart contract (in solidity) that I'm calling:

```
function getAllPendingRewardsByAddress(address _addr) public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 pendingRewardsFromSnapshot;
    for (uint256 i = 1; i < currentMonth; i++) {
        pendingRewardsFromSnapshot += getPendingRewardPerSnapshot(i, _addr);
    }

    return pendingRewardsFromSnapshot;
}
```

... and here's my frontend code that I'm calling to access the data:

```
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
  const accounts = await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
  const pendingRewards = await dividendContract.getAllPendingRewardsByAddress(accounts[0])
  console.log("PENDING", pendingRewards)
```

I've already tried the following debugging steps:

1. I've put the hexadecimal address directly in `getAllPendingRewardsByAddress("ADDRESS")`, no dice.
2. I've verified that the ABI is correct.
3. I've tried calling other views, they all seem to be working fine.

Some hunches I have...

- Is this something to do with having a for loop in a view? Maybe EthersJS needs more gas to properly execute the for loop, or something along those lines?
- ^ building off this... maybe it's something to do with assigning a local variable `pendingRewardsFromSnapshot` values that is causing the TX to not have enough gas?

I'm scratching my head with this one, never seen an issue like this before. Was wondering if anyone has had a similar problem, please let me know and thanks so much!

Comment: I quickly tested out my hypothesis of the for loop being an issue with a o(1) function call, called `getPendingRewardPerSnapshot()`. Once again, I get the result fine in Remix, but `0x00` on the frontend. Super super odd.

Comment: what did you get while you use  toString in the pendingRewards big Number ?   eg: pendingRewards.toString()

Comment: Wondering if the root of the problem lies in my interdependence on different smart contracts. I just realized that both of these function calls rely on another smart contract to properly get data, for example:
`function getBalanceOfCallerWithPrecisionPerSnapshot(uint256 _snapshotId) public view returns (uint256) {return TESTG.balanceOfAt(msg.sender, _snapshotId) * 10 ** percentagePrecision; }`

^ I am using TESTG, an outside contract, in both the `PendingRewards` function calls. Maybe that's the underlying issue? Not sure why it would work fine in Remix though...

Comment: @sms I'm getting "0"

Comment: then make sure you are calling dividendContract is deployed & then you are calling the contract with the respective address..

Comment: Hm yes both of those are correct, I am able to call other views from the contract no problem.

Comment: well then it needs debugging.. please provide minimum reproducible code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247611/discussion-between-user3430084-and-sms).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, apparently EthersJS calls views with a separate account than the one I was calling the view from (really weird). Anyways, I had to change one of my supporting views (`getBalanceOfCallerWithPrecisionPerSnapshot`) to use a passed address instead of msg.sender, and that fixed my problem. If you have a similar problem, check there. Thanks for being my rubber duck @sms!